# Fit the image size (stored in assets folder) into different size of screen

Tags: android

I have all my images in the assets file for showing in my andorid app. In order to fit the resolution of most of the android phone, I have created most of the images at size 1280 * 800 with resolution 160 dpi. I am not sure if it's a proper way...

However, when I try to run the app, it seems that the phone could not adjust the image automatically. I would like to ask how to code the program so that the phone could adjust the image according to the phone screen size?

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use 1280*800 image size because on some devices you will receive an out of memory exception because the images are to big for smaller devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1280 x 800 isn't a resolution that is actually supported by any device.  Honeycomb devices (which have that resolution) all allot space for the Action bar and the Status bar, so you need to account for that, if you're trying to make images that are full screen.  You can set your images to preserve their aspect ratio, and then set them to fill parent vertically and wrap content horizontally (or vice versa) and you will wind up seeing them looking like they scale correctly, and leave them at 72dpi The devices will display them correctly.

```
<ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: 'Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

Assets.firstPage = g.newPixmap("first_page.png", PixmapFormat.RGB565);

game.setScreen(new StartupScreen(game));'

I store the image file in Assets. But it seems that there is a similar functions that allows me to adjust the view bounds. Anyway to do the adjustment through this way?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing it this way, but if you want to draw it yourself you can just pull the screen width and height and run the bitmap through a matrix that scales it to those dimensions.

Comment: As i want to use the code to control the screen instead of creating the gui directly. This is my first android program and i m not sure it's a good way to do so.

Comment: pull the screen width and height and run the bitmap through a matrix that scales it to those dimensions

I think that's the way I shall follow. Is there any example I could refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it would help but its better to use dip (density independent pixel) instead of dpi, where the latter depends on the screen density and the former doesn't.

Comment: isn't the density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen? is it right to set the resolution as 160dpi?